# OpenVPN GUI stopps working

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, vpn, openvpn

I finally configured my OpenVPN Server v5 installed on Windows 7 machine. I have 25 clients which can reach it, ping it and do all the network traffic through the VPN. However, I need my server to be up and running 24/7.

I had to leave it for 2 days (I turned off the automatic logging off in Windows 7), but when I came back, I saw OpenVPN GUI stopped working, was closed, I couldnt even see its icon in menu at the bottom of the Window's Desktop, I needed to run it again (I run it as administrator every time). Since I need it to be started 24/7 its a huge problem for me. Is it Windows related or its OpenVPN's fault?

Comment: Why rely on a desktop program? OpenVPN can already run as a Windows Service.

Comment: @DanielB: I have OpenVPN installed as service and configured it to start automatically, but when the OpenVPN GUI is turned off, I cant connect to server, even if the service works ..

Comment: Well then I guess the configuration is not working. Try to log to a file somewhere (always use absolute paths) to see whether the service starts at all and, if so, why it’s not working.